# execution flow of program when encounter exception oracle PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql, plsqldeveloper

when we encounter an exception , the pointer will move to the exception part and if exception is handled will pointer come back or it move to the next part.?????

case 1: system defined exception

case 2: user defined exception

```
DECLARE
    var_dividend   NUMBER := 24;
    var_divisor    NUMBER := 0;
    var_result     NUMBER;
    exception_div_zero EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    IF  var_divisor = 0
    THEN
        RAISE exception_div_zero;
    END IF;

    var_result := var_dividend / var_divisor;

    dbms_output.put_line(var_result);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN exception_div_zero THEN
        dbms_output.put_line(var_result);
END;
```

i want to know when the the exception encounter
after executing exception part will pointer come back to the next statement or it just exist the program.??enter code here

Answer (score 3):

From the Oracle [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS99872) -

After an exception handler runs, control transfers to the next statement of the enclosing block. If there is no enclosing block, then:

If the exception handler is in a subprogram, then control returns to the invoker, at the statement after the invocation.

If the exception handler is in an anonymous block, then control transfers to the host environment (for example, SQL*Plus)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't go back to where you where. Rather the code keeps going after the exception handling.

Check this test out:

```
begin
  dbms_output.put_line('One');

  <<inner_one>>
  begin
    raise no_data_found;
    dbms_output.put_line('Two');
  exception
    when no_data_found then
      dbms_output.put_line('Three');
  end inner_one;

  dbms_output.put_line('Four');

  raise no_data_found;

  dbms_output.put_line('Five');

exception
  when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('Six');
end;
```

The output is:

```
One
Three
Four
Six
```

So Oracle's version of Try / Catch is to use anonymous blocks inside your blocks. You can nest blocks 255 times, which is a lot..

Example of using sub-block to parse a date string, if it fails, use current date/time.:

```
declare
  l_date date;
begin
  -- some code
  -- parse date
  begin
    l_date := to_date(:input1, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
  exception
    when others then
      l_date := sysdate;
  end;

  --some more code
end;
```

Regards
Olafur